# Cant Exit the App After Make BackButton Override Method in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So Previously I wanted to make my app to go back to MainPage after the Pyshical BackButton is pressed. I've already done that but the problem is when I am on MainPage and press the Pyhsical Button, instead of closing the App it doesn't go anywhere. The second problem is when the page stack is 2 (MainPage > News > NewsDetail) it goes directly to MainPage (DetailNews > MainPage). What I want to do is to pop to previouse Page (DetailNews > News > MainPage > ). Here is my full code for overide the backbutton

```
  public bool DoBack
        {
            get
            {
                MasterDetailPage mainPage = App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage;

                if (mainPage != null)
                {
                    bool canDoBack = mainPage.Detail.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 1 || mainPage.IsPresented;

                    // we are on a top level page and the Master menu is NOT showing
                    if (!canDoBack)
                    {
                        // don't exit the app just show Dashboard
                        //mainPage.IsPresented = true;

                        Type page = typeof(DrawerPage);

                        mainPage.Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page));
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
```

What Code should i Add or change here to do that, Any Sugestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im Already Found the solution im override OnBackButtonPressed in every Detail Page

```
  protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
                    Application.Current.MainPage = new DrawerPage();
                });

                return true;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

**The first problem:**
You logic is wrong. You need to return true if you want to stay on MainPage.

```
  public bool DoBack
        {
            get
            {
                MasterDetailPage mainPage = App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage;

                if (mainPage != null)
                {
                    bool canDoBack = mainPage.Detail.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 1 || mainPage.IsPresented;

                    // we are on a top level page and the Master menu is NOT showing
                    if (!canDoBack)
                    {
                        // don't exit the app just show Dashboard
                        //mainPage.IsPresented = true;

                        Type page = typeof(DrawerPage);

                        mainPage.Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page));
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
```

**The second problem:**
The reason why it goes directly to MainPage from DetailsNews is because you call PopToRoot instead of Pop. Read this [article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical/).

Comment: yes it can close, but it close everything when im in NewsPage its go to MainPage then Close immediately its look like the mainpage condition is always null so its never return else condition. So the else condition is already right it must return true , now the question why its never return else condition even if i in MainPage

Comment: I am not able to answer this. This is just a small piece of code. I would suggest you to use debugger and inspect what is in App.Current.MainPage and other parts.

Comment: i already debug my code, and i find my problem , the NavigationStack.Count is always 1 thats the problem when im in the MainPage the NavigationStack is 1 and when im Navigating to News the NavigationStack is 1 t0o. What make that happen ? why the NavigationStack is always 1 any suggestion ?

Comment: You probably doesn’t call push(DetailNews) on News page and instead of this you assign DetailNews to MainPage.Detail.

Comment: yes im using this   Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page)); , and i tried  Detail.Navigation.PushAsync((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page)); its work , but it only works once, the navigationstack.count is 2 but when i tried to navigating again to the news the navigationstack count is only 1. Is that a bug ? or i need to add some code

Comment: I don’t think it is a bug. Whenever you push it increase navigationstack.count and if you call Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)... it resets your navigatinstack and count is 1.

Comment: but there is a problem, From MainPage im push to News my NavigationStack.Count in my debug is 2 then im back to MainPage, then i try to push to News Again but in my debug the NavigationStack is not Increasing its still 1, but the previouslly it increase to 2 why that happen ?

Comment: Could you please share your project or create just empty project replicating this issue.